# Drupal migration

Tags: drupal, migration

I need to make a drupal migration from 5.1 version to 6.17 or greater. Really, we will appreciate any type of help

Comment: Yeah, you didn't ask a question, so there's nothing to answer.

Comment: Try search engine (google) with "drupal migration 5 6".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow these instructions:**

1. Make a backup of your Drupal instance (database). (For ex: with MySQL)
2. Download the latest release of your current Drupal version.
3. Extract the [tar ball or zip] Drupal package.
4. Set your site on maintenance mode (For ex: How on D7)
5. Delete all the files & folders inside your original Drupal instance except for /sites and its sub-folders. This assumes that all of your custom work - including themes - is in the recommended spot - the /sites folder tree. If you have made custom changes elsewhere, you will need to either preserve them or plan to replace them later. **Warning:** If your Drupal installation is built from a distribution your site will break if you delete the /profiles folder. Don't delete the profile folder that corresponds to the distribution you installed, for example, /profiles/kickstart if you installed Drupal Commerce Kickstart.
6. Copy all the folders and files except /sites from inside the extracted Drupal package [tar ball or zip package] into your original Drupal instance location.
7. Some updates do not include changes to setting.php and some do. If the update release includes changes to settings.php you will need to replace your old `settings.php` in `.../sites/default/` with the new one, and then edit the site-specific entries (eg database name, user, and password) in the setting file.
8. If you have modified files such as .htaccess or `robots.txt` re-apply those changes to the new files.
9. If you have a favicon.ico file that was deleted replace it too
10. Login to your site as administrator or as user no 1
11. Run update.php by navigating to http://yourdrupalsitename/update.php and follow the process to update your Drupal instance.
12. Disable maintenance mode.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://drupal.org/upgrade/) page will help you :)